# Converting between text files and binary files in C++

Tags: c++

For converting an ordinary text file into binary and then convert that binary file back to a text file so that the first text file equals with the last text file, I have wrote below code.
But the *bintex* text file and the *final* text file aren't equal. I don't know which part of code is incorrect.
Input sample ("bintex") contains this: **1983 1362**
The result ("final") contains this: **959788084**
which of course are not equal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() try
{
    string name1 = "bintex", name2 = "texbin", name3 = "final";

     ifstream ifs1(name1.c_str());
     if(!ifs1) error("Can't open file for reading.");

     vector<int>v1, v2;
     int i;
     while(ifs1.read(as_bytes(i), sizeof(int)));
     v1.push_back(i);
     ifs1.close();

     ofstream ofs1(name2.c_str(), ios::binary);
     if(!ofs1) error("Can't open file for writting.");
     for(int i=0; i<v1.size(); i++)
         ofs1 << v1[i];
         ofs1.close();

     ifstream ifs2(name2.c_str(), ios::binary);
      if(!ifs2) error("Can't open file for reading.");

         while(ifs2.read(as_bytes(i), sizeof(int)));
          v2.push_back(i);
          ifs2.close();

     ofstream ofs2(name3.c_str());
     if(!ofs2) error("Can't open file for writting.");
     for(int i=0; i<v2.size(); i++)
         ofs2 << v2[i];
         ofs2.close();

        keep_window_open();
        return 0;
}

//********************************

catch(exception& e) 
{
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ex Python coder? :D  ...

Comment: @herohuyongtao, you should not fix code in a question. <- you didn't just change format as stated below, you added a set of brackets.

Comment: @OGHaza my bad, just changed its format though. Thanks.

Comment: I dont think the patch on the strange try/catch thing is central to the issues tho. Btw, since the code has multiple failures, you will likely need more than one fix before its ready to go.

Comment: Yeah you don't should fix the problem in the question. It causes confusing of question poster.

Answer (score 1):

What is this?

```
 while(ifs1.read(as_bytes(i), sizeof(int)));
```

It looks like a loop that reads all input and throws it away.  The line afterward suggests that you should be using braces instead of a semicolon there, and doing the write in the block.

Comment: its true, you have a trailing comma on the for loop.

Comment: Same bug in lower loops too.

Comment: Oh there are plenty of bugs--I just picked a really severe one near the top.  :)

Comment: OK, I removed that two wrong semicolons (from whiles). But now differences are more than before. final text files now contains: 859387192926298674959461683892613171

Answer (score 0):

Your read and write operations aren't  symmetric.

```
ifs1.read(as_bytes(i), sizeof(int))
```

grabs 4 bytes, and dumps the values into the char* its passed.

```
ofs1 << v1[i];
```

output the integer in v[i] as text. Those are very very different formats. 
If you used `>>` to read you would have a lot more success.

To expound, the first read might look like this `{'1','9','8','3'}`, which I would guess would be the `959788084` you are seeing when you pun it to an int. Your second read would be `{' ','1','3','6'}`, like not what you'd hoped for either.

Comment: The question is: from where does `as_bytes` get the `char*`?  And what format does he actually have in his file.

Comment: @James, I assumed it was a cast style thing, from the read function sig, which takesa char* forhte place it stashes the data. Comparing to read in C, you would often pass `&i` as the place to put a `sizeof(int)` thing.

Comment: That's what I suspect as well, but it would be nice to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear (to me, at least), what you are trying to do.
When you say that the orginal file contains 1983 1262, what do
you really mean?  That it contains two four byte integers, in
some unspecified format, whose values are 1983 and 1262?  If so,
the problem is probably due to your machine not using the same
format.  You cannot, in general, just read bytes (using
`istream::read`) and expect them to mean anything in your
machine's internal format.  You have to read the bytes into
a buffer, and unformat them, according to the format with which
they were written.

Of course, opening a stream in binary mode *doesn't* mean that
the actual data are in some binary format; it just affects
things like how (or more strictly speaking, whether) line
endings are encoded, and how end of file is recognized. 
(Strictly speaking, a binary file is not divided into lines.  It
is just a sequence of bytes.  Of course, some of those bytes
might have values that you, in your program, interpret and new
line characters.)  If your file actually contains nine bytes
with characters corresponding to `"1983 1362", then you'll have
to parse them as a text format, even if the file is written in
binary.  You can do this by reading the entire file into
a string, and using`std::istringstream`; _or_, on most common
systems (but not necessarily on all exotics) by using`>>` to
read, just as you would with a text file.

EDIT:

Just a simple reminder: you don't show the code for `as_bytes`,
but I'm willing to guess that there's a `reinterpret_cast` in
it.  And any time you have to use a reinterpret cast, you can be
very sure that what you're doing isn't portable, and if it's
supposed to be portable, you're doing it wrong.